# How should I design an E-commerce Class Diagram?

Tags: java, architecture, uml, software-design, class-diagram

I am learning software design now. I am a front-end guy so this may be a stupid question, but I really want to know the answer. Hope you could help me.

I have to design an E-commerce system. More specifically, I am designing the buying system in E-commerce. I have done some research on how to do it and found EAV. But after knowing the EAV is the anti-pattern, I don't want to use it and also I have to keep it simple for a beginner like me to understand the design.

Here is the `class` diagram I have designed by myself.
[image: My E-commerce Buying function Class Diagram]

And of course, I don't think this design is correct. I have spent like three days doing research and thinking about how to solve the `Product` and `ProductType` problem.

I just want to have a product like an iPhone, for example, has the attributes belong to the phone, a coke has the attributes belong to the drink, etc.

**How could I do this?**

Please tell me how to solve this problem in a simple way, cause I am new to this. Some articles or books about software design could be appreciated too.

Thank you <3

Comment: What is EAV? I've never heard about it.

Comment: @NomadMaker EAV stands for Entity Attribute Value. It's the design pattern that Magento uses to create their database.

Comment: But you don't reference Magneto anywhere in your question.

Comment: @NomadMaker You are right. I don't reference Magento anywhere in my question because I don't think only Magento uses that design, and also I don't use Magento or EAV in my design. I just want to keep my question clear and focus, so sorry if I have confused you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you know that all the products have (at least) a product type. And you know that a product type instance will end up being a drink, a telephone, etc. So, you first need

## Product Type Abstractization

You will need to make sure that `ProductType` is either an `interface` or an `abstract class` or a base `class`. An `interface` is a declared entity type, whose capabilities are known, but not implemented. It is the job of the classes implementing the `interface` to implement its methods. An `abstract class` is a fully declared, but only partially defined entity type. If you have an `abstract class`, then you are able to implement some of its methods, but you delegate the implementation of some of its method to its implementing subclasses. A base `class` is a `class` which is fully defined.

So your first decision is to make `ProductType` one of the following:

- `interface`
- `abstract class`
- base `class`

You will need to think about what the common capabilities of product types are. If they should have some methods which work exactly the same, then you do not necessarily need an interface, but you will need an `abstract class` or a base `class`. If you decide not to define an `interface` at this point, that's fine. Later you can define it if you realize that you need it anyway. So, assuming that the methods of the separate product types are at least partially common, you will need to have some class. By default it should be a base `class`, that is, a normal `class` which has all the methods a `ProductType` should have implemented. Son't worry, if some specific product types should behave in a different manner in the case of some methods in comparison to the base `class`, you can always [override](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/) base `class` methods for subclasses.

However, you might need an `abstract class`. In order to decide whether an `abstract class` is the way to go is to find out whether there is at least such a method that should NOT be implemented by the base `class` in any circumstances, because that method is always known only on subclass-level. For example, if you have an `evaluate` method, then you will probably need to implement it separately for your product types, because a phone is evaluated in a different manner in comparison to car.

---

Next, you need to define specific `ProductType` subclasses, that is, classes which `extends`/`implement` `ProductType`. We know that a `ProductType` may have 0 or more Products, but can a product be of more product types?

## Handling one-to-many vs. many-to-many relations

A product will need to have a `ProductType` if there is no possibility for more product types to be associated to a single `Product`. Otherwise you will need a collection of product types by product.

---

## Abstractization of Product

Since `Product` is also something much more general, you will probably need to invoke `Product` methods from `ProductType`. This means that you will need to decide whether `Product` is an:

- `interface`
- `abstract class`
- base `class`

as well, with a similar thought process as the one you have used when decided what `ProductType` should be.

## ProductType and Product trees

It's a big question whether there can be subtypes, sub-subtypes, etc. for `ProductType` and `Product`. If that's the case, you will need to implement trees for them with proper insert/update/delete/search functionalities, as you need them

## Use your abstractizations

Whenever possible, do not refer to specific product types, because then you will have to copy-paste that code for other products and product types. Whenever the same pattern is true for all your product types or products, refer them by their most `abstract` representation (their `interface`, `abstract class` or `base class`, respectively) and only use concrete types at instantiation and when you are forced to.

## Factories

Use factory methods for instantiation instead of constructors, because a factory method can return the instance of a subtype if that's what you need.

Comment: Wow! I very much appreciate your detailed answer. The design process you give me helps a lot in my learning. But I don't understand the ProductType and Product trees part. Isn't it the ProductType is the subtype of the Product? Could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn ProductType and Product should be separate entities. Food is a ProductType, which means that Food inherits/implement ProductType. Hamburger is a Food, which means that Hamburger extends Food. Cheeseburger is a Hamburger, which means that Cheeseburger extends Hamburger. Actual products are probably tied to brands. Let's assume there is a restaurant called HamBurger. Now, they have a Fantasy Burger, which is a Product (implements/inherits Product) and it might have subtypes.

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn logically, ProductType seems to indicate the conceptual background of products while actual products are produced/distributed by certain companies. When I'm talking about shoes in general, I might talk about wearing them, ways of choosing them, but am less interested about their brand. When I talk about Adidas sport shoes, then I'm thinking about it more concretely. It is worth to draw a line between the concept of products (ProductType) and the actual product entities (Product), especially when we deal with E-Commerce.

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn for example, when you create an E-Commerce project, users may need to search by product types, their subtypes, etc. and they may also search by brands. You will not necessarily need ProductType or Product trees, especially initially, but it's important to keep in mind that as a possibility, so, if you need to have the subcategory of the subcategory, etc., then the word "tree" should spring to mind. If my answer clarified the way forward, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn I have to confess that I am too lazy to read books about programming, unfortunately. For mathematical background though I can recommend Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming. It's a very old book and very mathematical, but it was a great read for me many years ago. I can also recommend Pragmatic Programmer by David Thomas and Andrew Hunt (there is a 2020 edition as well).

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn specifically about the software design I found Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides, which seems to be good, but I did not read it.